# how to handle missing data in SQL 2008 r2 using select statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

For each successful login there is "Logged-in" entry and for each successful logout there is "Logged-out" entry but in case user close the browser then 
"Logged-out" event is not captured which is acceptable but to overcome this i want a dummy entry which shows "Logged-out" for the same user
is there any way to handle it using sql query in 2008 r2?

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityLog](
[UserID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[LogDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Activity] [varchar](500) NULL,
```

)

```
    insert into [ActivityLog] values ('Maker-CO','2019-05-20 11:57:42.500','Logged-in')
    insert into [ActivityLog] values ('Maker-CO','2019-05-20 12:39:06.203','Logged-out')
    insert into [ActivityLog] values ('Maker-CO','2019-05-20 12:41:48.537','Logged-in')
    insert into [ActivityLog] values ('Maker-CO','2019-05-20 12:42:32.467','Logged-in')
```

below is my select command

```
    select userid,Logdate,activity from activitylog order by logdate
```

but I want output as

```
    userid      Logdate                 activity 
    maker-co    2019-05-20 11:57:42.500    Logged-in
    maker-co    2019-05-20 12:39:06.203    Logged-out
    maker-co    2019-05-20 12:41:48.537    Logged-in
    maker-co    2019-05-20 12:41:48.537    Logged-out
    maker-co    2019-05-20 12:42:32.467    Logged-in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with JS.

```
   window.onunload = function () {
        //logout code or AJAX func. here...
    }
```

And if you want to logout with server side func., You should use ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: <<PAGE_URL>>/<<FUNC_NAME>>,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: <<if you use parameter>>,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) 
    {
        //your code 

    },
    error: function(result) 
    {
        alert('error occured');
        alert(result.responseText);
        window.location.href="XYZ.aspx?Exception="+result.responseText;
    },
    async: true
});
```

Comment: I want to handle this using Sql query